# Subjects in Angular

Tags: angular

So imagine you have an angular app with the below component and service files. In a component the users subscribe to this subject in the service file.

Now imagine that someone makes the server request in the service file and gets the response from the server.

When we receive the server response and trigger the Subject with the next() method, will only we receive the data in the component that is subscribed to this Subject or basically every person who is currently using this app and has this subscription open in his component?

**Component**

```js
export class exampleComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.exampleService.exampleSubject().subscribe();
  }
}
```

**Service**

```js
export class exampleService {
  exampleSubject = new Subject();

  someOtherMethodWithHttpRequest() {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(data => this.exampleSubject.next()));
  }
}
```

Comment: any component that has subscribed to the subject in the service will get the data

Comment: you will find it when you try it out.

Comment: I don't know how to put my app online :D

Comment: go through [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-subjects-5c585188c3e1)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Answer (score 3):

It will because it is a Subject, and subjects are multicast.

edited: my initial answer was *no, because only BehaviorSubject and ReplaySubject are multicast*. This is **wrong**, all Subjects are multicast.

Using a BehaviorSubject in this case is a good idea though: it guarantees that every subscriber will receive the value from the api call, even if they subscribe after the api call occurred. If you subscribe to a Subject after it has emitted its value, you will never receive the value from that api call.

Comment: Ok, I'll check them out.

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear. If my friend Joe is using my app at his home and I at my place. When I would receive back the data after a server request and thus trigger the subject in this service, he would receive the data as well when he's subscribed to this subject in his component, right?

Comment: @tilly, no, he won't! your client app is running in your client browser (the code is in your client, chrome, for instance, not in Joe's). Joe needs to call the same service has you in order to get the notification. However, how to you think it works? you click "add user" for instance, and Joe receive a notification in his place, "the user was added"?? Not it doesn't work like that. What multicast means is it broadcasts to all the subscribers, yes, but all the subscriber in your client, your browser, not all around the world.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for making that clear.